# High quality test cases for Sudoku Solver

Tags: testing, sudoku, testcase

I'm making my own version of Sudoku Solver. Are there any open source test cases that I can use to test the efficiency of my algorithm (I don't just want randomized test cases. I want test cases that are marked easy, medium, hard).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The difficulty measurement of SuDoKus are debatable. There are no reference system for the measurement. So don't compare across multiple collections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find some large datasets for Sudoku benchmarking and testing in this project: https://github.com/t-dillon/tdoku

See data.zip for the puzzles.

See https://github.com/t-dillon/tdoku/blob/master/benchmarks/README.md for descriptions of the datasets, their sources, and their difficulties.